# Styles at media quary applies only partially

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, jsx

I am trying to make mobile navigation but my styles at medea applying only partially, to be precisely it applies background color but not flex styles.

JSX

```
import classes from "./Header.module.scss";
import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";
import { FaBars } from "react-icons/fa";
import { IoMdClose } from "react-icons/io";

const Header = () => {
  const smoothScrollToSection = (id: string) => {
    const element = document.getElementById(id);
    if (element) {
      element.scrollIntoView({
        behavior: "smooth",
      });
    }
  };

  return (
    <header className={classes.header}>
      <nav className={`${classes.nav} container`}>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <NavLink to="/" className={classes.logo}>
              Quibeez
            </NavLink>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <ul className={classes['nav-link']}>
          <li>
            <NavLink className={classes.link} to="/">
              Home
            </NavLink>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a
              href="#about"
              className={classes.link}
              onClick={() => smoothScrollToSection("about")}
            >
              About
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a
              href="#contact"
              className={classes.link}
              onClick={() => smoothScrollToSection("contact")}
            >
              Contact
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a
              href="#menu"
              className={classes["menu-link"]}
              onClick={() => smoothScrollToSection("menu")}
            >
              Menu
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <ul>
          <li className={classes["mobile"]}>
            <button>
              <FaBars className={classes["btn-menu-open"]} />
            </button>
            <button>
              <IoMdClose className={classes["btn-menu-close"]} />
            </button>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>
  );
};

export default Header;
```

Styles

```
@import "../styles/mixins/mixins.scss";
@import "../styles/variables/variables.scss";

.header {
  background-color: $orange;
  padding: 2.3rem;

  .nav {
    @include flex(space-between, center);

    ul {
      @include flex(center, center, row, 4.6rem);
      list-style: none;
      font-family: Poppins;

      li {
        cursor: pointer;
      }
    }

    .link {
      font-size: 1.6rem;
      text-decoration: none;
      color: $black-secondary;
    }

    .menu-link {
      color: $orange;
      font-size: 1.6rem;
      font-weight: 700;
      background-color: $white-primary;
      padding: 3px 16px 5px 16px;
      text-decoration: none;
      box-shadow: 0px 4px 4px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
      border-radius: 1.6rem;
    }

    .logo {
      color: $white-secondary;
      font-size: 2.8rem;
      font-family: Lily Script One;
    }
  }

  .mobile {
    @include flex(center center);
    display: none;

    button {
      border: none;
      background: none;
      cursor: pointer;
      @include flex(center center);
    }

    .btn-menu-open,
    .btn-menu-close {
      width: 2.4rem;
      height: 2.4rem;
    }

    .btn-menu-close {
      display: none;
    }
  }
}

@media (max-width: 60em) {
  .nav {
    .nav-link { 
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      background-color: blue;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100vh;
      
    }

  }
}
```

I am expecting to make mobile nav a 100% width and 100vh with display flex and flex-direction: column, it's my first time making mobile menu with react, I would appriciate your help guys.